# Failed to grant permissions for application <application name>

Tags: azure

I am just trying to do grant permission for my application after registering with Azure AD, but I am getting this error 
Azure AD: Failed to grant permission for application

Comment: You will get more attention if you show exact steps you are trying and what values you are putting there.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, two factors need to be considered:

1. Permission. Applications in Azure AD rely on consent in order to gain access to necessary resources or APIs. The Grant permissions button does administrator consent for the tenant, so you should be an admin in the Azure AD tenant to do this.
2. Configuration mistake. [Here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Failed-to-grant-permissions-for-application-lt-application-name/m-p/224507#M7100) is a similar issue. He was registering his app by choosing server side web-app but it is actually a Native App.